# C code on Linux under gdb runs differently if run standalone?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, gdb

I have built a plain C code on Linux (Fedora) using code-sorcery tool-chain. This is for ARM Cortex-A8 target. This code is running on a Cortex A8 board, running embedded Linux.

When I run this code for some test case, which does dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`) for some large size (10MB), it crashes after some time giving error message as below:

```
select 1 (init), adj 0, size 61, to kill
select 1030 (syslogd), adj 0, size 64, to kill
select 1032 (klogd), adj 0, size 74, to kill
select 1227 (bash), adj 0, size 378, to kill
select 1254 (ppp), adj 0, size 1069, to kill
select 1255 (TheoraDec_Corte), adj 0, size 1159, to kill
send sigkill to 1255 (TheoraDec_Corte), adj 0, size 1159
Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
```

Then, when I debug this code for the same test case using gdb built for the target, the point where this dynamic memory allocation happens, code fails to allocate that memory and `malloc` returns `NULL`. But during normal stand-alone run, I believe `malloc` should be failing to allocate but it strangely might not be returning `NULL`, but it crashes and the OS kills my process.

1. Why is this behaviour different when run under gdb and when without debugger?
2. Why would `malloc` fails yet not return a `NULL`. Could this be possible, or the reason for the error message I am getting is else?
3. How do I fix this?

thanks,

-AD

Comment: Why do you say you expect your 10MB `malloc` to fail anyway? You don't have that much memory on the system?

Comment: What's that error message you mention?

Comment: Missed the error message in OP, edited now to add teh same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, for this part of the question, there is a surefire answer:

> Why would malloc fails yet not return a NULL. Could this be possible, or the reason for the error message i am getting is else?

In Linux, by default the kernel interfaces for allocating memory almost never fail outright.  Instead, they set up your [page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) in such a way that on the first access to the memory you asked for, the CPU will generate a [page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault), at which point the kernel handles this and looks for physical memory that will be used for that (virtual) page.  So, in an out-of-memory situation, you can ask the kernel for memory, it will "succeed", and the first time you try to touch that memory it returned back, *this* is when the allocation actually fails, killing your process.  (Or perhaps some other unfortunate victim.  There are some heuristics for that, which I'm not incredibly familiar with.  See "[oom-killer](http://www.google.com/search?q=oom+killer)".)

Some of your other questions, the answers are less clear for me.

> Why is this behaviour different when run under gdb and when without debugger?

It could be (just a guess really) that GDB has its own `malloc`, and is tracking your allocations somehow.  On a somewhat related point, I've actually frequently found that heap bugs in my code often aren't reproducible under debuggers.  This is frustrating and makes me scratch my head, but it's basically something I've pretty much figured one has to live with...

> How do i fix this?

This is a bit of a sledgehammer solution (that is, it changes the behavior for *all* processes rather than just your own, and it's generally not a good idea to have your program alter global state like that), but you can write the string `2` to `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`.  See [this link](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_overcommit_memory.html) that I got from a Google search.

Failing that...  I'd just make sure you're not allocating more than you expect to.

Comment: For an embedded system like this, running a tightly controlled set of processes, turning off overcommit is probably the right way to run.  You can make the change permanent in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, if you have a reasonably standard bootup sequence.

Answer (score 2):

By definition running under a debugger is different than running standalone.  Debuggers can and do hide many of the bugs.  If you compile for debugging you can add a fair amount of code, similar to compiling completely unoptimized (allowing you to single step or watch variables for example).  Where compiling for release can remove debugging options and remove code that you needed, there are many optimization traps you can fall into.  I dont know from your post who is controlling the compile options or what they are.

Unless you plan to deliver the product to be run under the debugger you should do your testing standalone.  Ideally do your development without the debugger as well, saves you from having to do everything twice.

It sounds like a bug in your code, slowly re-read your code using new eyes as if you were explaining it to someone, or perhaps actually explain it to someone, line by line.  There may be something right there that you cannot see because you have been looking at it the same way for too long.  It is amazing how many times and how well that works.

I could also be a compiler bug.  Doing things like printing out the return value, or not can cause the compiler to generate different code.  Adding another variable and saving the result to that variable can kick the compiler to do something different.  Try changing the compiler options, reduce or remove any optimization options, reduce or remove the debugger compiler options, etc.

Is this a proven system or are you developing on new hardware?  Try running without any of the caches enabled for example.  Working in a debugger and not in standalone, if not a compiler bug can be a timing issue, single stepping flushes the pipline, mixes the cache up differently, gives the cache and memory system an eternity to come up with a result which it doesnt have in real time.

In short there is a very long list of reasons why running under a debugger hides bugs that you cannot find until you test in the final deliverable like environment, I have only touched on a few.  Having it work in the debugger and not in standalone is not unexpected, it is simply how the tools work.  It is likely your code, the hardware, or your tools based on the description you have given so far.

The fastest way to eliminate it being your code or the tools is to disassemble the section and inspect how the passed values and return values are handled.  If the return value is optimized out there is your answer.

Are you compiling for a shared C library or static?  Perhaps compile for static...

Comment: @dwelch:Thanks for all the pointers. I have updated the error messg. which i messed out in OP, if it helps to narrow further.thanks.